# QT slots and signals fail

Tags: c++, qt, signals, connect, slot

Hi there i got problem with signal and slots in qt.
In main i have created object of mainwindow.
in mainwindow.cpp i creating object of another class(modbus_tcp).
i also creating connection here

```
void MainWindow::on_ConnectB_clicked()
{

    modbus_tcp appts;
    appts.slave();
    connect(&appts,SIGNAL(msgSended(QString)),this,SLOT(msgEdit(QString)));
}
```

between slot declared in mainwindow.cpp/h

```
public slots:
void msgEdit(QString m);

void MainWindow::msgEdit(QString m)
{
ui->sendEdit->setText(m);
ui->recvEdit->setText(m);
//QMessageBox::information(0,"bad", "nope nope nope");
}
```

and signal declared in modbus_tcp.h

```
signals:
void msgSended(QString);
```

next i emiting signal in modbus_tcp.cpp

```
emit msgSended("asdasd");
```

and nothing happen

when i trying to emit in mainwindow.cpp its working

any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void MainWindow::on_ConnectB_clicked()
{

    modbus_tcp appts;
    appts.slave();
    connect(&appts,SIGNAL(msgSended(QString)),this,SLOT(msgEdit(QString)));
}
```

`appts` was created in stack, so it will be deleted at the end of slot execution. Try to create it in the heap(try to use pointer).

```
void MainWindow::on_ConnectB_clicked()
{

    modbus_tcp *appts = new modbus_tcp;
    connect(appts,SIGNAL(msgSended(QString)),this,SLOT(msgEdit(QString)));//first!
    appts->slave();//now you can call it
}
```

Use pointers, but first of all `connect`, and after this call `slave`. You emit signal in `slave`, but there is no connection in this time. You should do connection firstly and after that, you will be able to catch signals.

Comment: changed it not helped i'll add by editing slave function when im emitting it